# How do I Insert Into a User-created Table Name?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a code in Python that inserts data into a remote Postgresql database. I made the program accept a user input and created a table with the user input as the table name. However, when I INSERT INTO the table, I have to specify the name of the table to insert into. How do I specify the table I just created? For clarification, here is the line in my code I am having trouble with:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO [name_of_table_I_just_created] (column1, column2) VALUES (%s, %s);")
```

I created the table using cursor.execute(). `trial_name` is the user input:

```
    cursor.execute(f"""
            CREATE TABLE {trial_name} (
                id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                column1 VARCHAR,
                column2 VARCHAR
            );
        """)
```

I hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance.

I tried specifying the table I just created using %s, but that was for fields

Comment: Use the `psycopg2`  [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) module.

Comment: Why don't you like the solution you have posted?  It is correct, assuming you have taken steps to make sure it's safe.  It is unusual to have table names be a variable -- how are you going to fetch that table later?